How to access JSON that another script requested?
If you use your browser's devtools you can easily see the JSON as a response to an XHR request in the Networking tab. How to access the same JSON in your own Javascript, e.g. from the context of an browser extension?
I've figured it would be in the window.sessionStorage object but haven't found any leads there.

I think you are looking for this Intercept HTTP requests  .. but let me tell you it won't be an easy task if you were thinking that sessionStorage was a legit place to look for

Data only appears in sessionStorage if it's been put there explicitly.

It looks like you're trying to use javascript to retrieve data from the network tab.  That won't be possible from a page's javascript.   (as you state "e.g from a browser extension", implying other types of javascript such as the page's javascript - could just be a misuse of "e.g.")

A Firefox extension's background script can use webRequest.filterResponseData, while a content script can spoof the built-in XMLHttpRequest and/or fetch, example.

Does this answer your question? Chrome extension to read HTTP response
